My vue application is not getting loaded in hostinger...its showing Page Not Found The page you are looking for does not exist
Page Not Found The page you are looking for does not exist.
i ran npm run build ...got the dist files and imported to the public folder in my hostinger vps
gave specification in Nginx for the server block....everything is pointed correct...but the vue is not displayed.....

There is really hard to say something about your issue without at least a bit of additional information. What is your nginx config? What are the corresponding entries from the nginx access and error logs?
